# Question regard to this recursion function

Tags: c++

A code to find a factorial of an input n:

```
 #include <iostream>
using namespace std;

long long factorial(int num) {
    if (num == 0) {
        return 1;
    }
    else {
        return num * factorial(num-1);
    }
}

int main() {
    int num;
    cin >> num;
    cout << factorial(num) << endl;
}
```

My questions are:

1. Here written  factorial(num-1) then how can the variable num get decreased per loop ? The function will permanent use num-1 as its argument but num is not saved. I mean there should be num--; in the function. I have tried and printed out variable num at the end of the program and it was the same, num wasnt 0.
2. Here written     if (num == 0) {       return 1; } . When num get decreased to 0 then shouldn't the function takes 1 as it final value ? But it doesn't. Just like variable, when you write a = 1 at the end of the program; then doesnt matter what calculation happened to a before, the final value of a will be 1. And as I understand return 1; has the same effect, doesnt it ?

Many thanks

Comment: You do understand that every call of function the "num" parameter isn't the same, right?

Comment: this will most-likely result in a stack overflow error if factorial is given a negative number

Comment: @Acc-lab I actually didn't. I thought the value of num in every call of function is the same. But I understand now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recursive functions work exactly like non-recursive functions - there is no "loop" and nothing gets decremented.

Perhaps the substitution method could help.

Consider `factorial(2)`.

If we replace `num` with `2` in the function's body we get

```
if (2 == 0) {
    return 1;
}
else {
    return 2 * factorial(2-1);
}
```

In order to calculate this, we need `factorial(1)`, which becomes

```
if (1 == 0) {
    return 1;
}
else {
    return 1 * factorial(1-1);
}
```

And now we need `factorial(0)`:

```
if (0 == 0) {
    return 1;
}
else {
    return 0 * factorial(0-1);
}
```

This is clearly `1`, so now we can move back up and insert the calculated values in place of the function calls.

`factorial(1)`:

```
if (1 == 0) {
    return 1;
}
else {
    return 1 * 1;
}
```

which is `1`, and then `factorial(2)`:

```
if (2 == 0) {
    return 1;
}
else {
    return 2 * 1;
}
```

which is `2`.

Note that there is no "connection" between the recursive calls - they don't share any variables or other data, their arguments just happen to have the same name - and `return` does not return to the "topmost" caller but only to the most immediate one, just like other functions.

Comment: Thanks, I understand now. Many thank for your answer.

Comment: @Khang: Please mark the answer as "accepted" if appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

1. The original variable "num" is never decreased there.
   It's an integer, thus, is a value type. So, everytime by writing `factorial(num-1)` you create a new variable with the value (num-1) and pass it to the function. (e.g. if num was 5 then it would be like calling `factorial(4)`)
2. Again, "num" never gets decrased. You just pass a new variable that has the num-1 value. So, in the previous loop when the num was 1, and you called `factorial(num-1)` you just passed it's like calling `factorial(0)`, and here that 0 was just checked in the if statement and exited by returning 1.

Answer (score 0):

Lets break this down with a concrete example.  If you call `factorial(5)` then what happens is you run `if (num == 0)`, which is false, so you then run `return num * factorial(num-1);`, where `num` is `5` so it's `return 5 * factorial(4)`.  Now, in order for `return` to return, it needs to evaluate `factorial(4)`.  Just like `factorial(5)`, `factorial(4)` becomes `return 4 * factorial(3)`, this happens for 3, 2 and 1.  Once you are in `factorial(1)`, you get `return 1 * factorial(0)`, and `factorial(0)` passes `if (num == 0)`, so it is just `return 1`.

Putting all that together you get

```
return 5 * 4 * 3 * 2 * 1 * 1
```